# If one worships Lord Vishnu and smells pleasant out of nowhere during worship, what does it mean, a good sign or bad?

Tags: vishnu, spirituality

Hi this question might seem personal but it is important for just any devotee of Lord Vishnu...

I worship him and some times out of nowhere I start smelling Divine smells.... Not only me but people around me also smell the same Divine smells...

One of my occult practitioner friend told me that it is a sign of presence of Lord Vishnu.

Is it true? Is it written in any Shastras or Puranas etc?

Comment: Yes, blessing of Vishnu

Comment: do you have dhoop/agarbatti in puja room :) ?